# How to properly escape special characters in a resource file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, resources

I am working on a project and trying to add one string to a resource file. I've read that the resource file in an MVC 3 project is converted to XML and the special characters are automatically escaped, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I have tried using / and using %xx hexidecimal ways to enter special characters, but none of those work correctly either. Without escaping some of these characters, the code errors out. Here is the string in the resource file I'm trying to fix:

```
Minimum of 6 letters, numbers, and special characters, no spaces. Special characters include: !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, (, ), -, _, =, +, {, }, |, /, ?.
```

As you can see at the end, I am including the usage of a number of special characters, but something in those characters is not liked when running the code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Use the HTML codes, I just tested it and it works fine, e.g. single apostrophe `'` HTML code is `&#8217;`

Comment: Used this solution in Resources when had problems with apostrophes and Html.Encode. Worked.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use @"" as it is simpler than escaping every special character.

@"Minimum of 6 letters, numbers, and special characters, no spaces. Special characters include: !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, (, ), -, _, =, +, {, }, |, /, ?."

Comment: In my case this doesn't work. I still get the format error I have been getting. This is in a resource file(i.e. AdminResource.resx). I tried the @"string" but that didn't work.

Comment: Moving along this route, perhaps try adding this string to your Resource file programmatically? So, in a C# file, do something like `AddResource(key, value);`.

Comment: Are you saying put it in the ViewModel? Adding it to the regex like so: [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\#$\%^\&()\-_+.\'\`\~\/\=\?{}|]){6,255}$", ErrorMessageResourceType = AddResource(UsernameFormatError, "Minimum of 6 letters, numbers, and special characters, no spaces. Special characters include: !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, (, ), -, _, =, +, {, }, |, /, ?.")]?

Comment: Adding this to the regex/viewmodel did not work either. Tried it using "ErrorMessage = "string" and AddResource(key, value).

Comment: By process of elimination, I've found the "{" and "}" are the culprits behind it erroring out. So I'm just going to nix those and leave them out of the special characters to be included just to make things simple.

Comment: @Skrubb use {{  }} to scape { and }

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you edit a .resx file in Visual Studio, you should not escape any characters.